# Can I filter data to show current month from yesterdays date in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with data that provides more than current month. Since my reporting is viewed as snapshots of performance MTD, I need to find filter the data for current month (based on yesterdays date).

I have found a couple of macros that would work based on current date and time but can't figure out how to base it off yesterdays date.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to use a helper column?  If so, you can do this within excel using *=month(CellRef)=Month(Today()-1)*; the output is true/false and you can filter for True values.

Answer (score 1):

The `Now` function in VBA will get you the current date. You can subtract 1 from it to get yesterday's date.

```
Sub yesterdate()
  Dim vResult
  vResult = Now - 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DateAdd-method too, if u want to change years, months or time

```
Dim Yesterday As Date
Yesterday = DateAdd("d", -1, Date)  '<--- Now is also possible
MsgBox Format(YesterDay, "mmmm d, yyyy")
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22412864)

Comment: ty i'll take care of it, my answer overlapped with Greg_D's one

Comment: I didn't see Greg_D's answer in the queue. It deserves the same comment though.